# How to update web-installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 offline (saved layout)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 which was installed from the web. 
Meanwhile, the corporate firewall rules changed and it's no longer possible to update the installation (download.visualstudio.microsoft.com is blocked).

At home I was able to download a complete Visual Studio 2017 layout to an external drive.

Now, how can I instruct Visual Studio Installer to use the external drive layout instead of trying to download from the web?

Answer (score 1):

After googling a bit, I found some clues here and there, but never got a direct answer. I had to do some experiments until I found a very simple solution:

1. Open folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances` (or equivalent in your machine). This folder should contain a subfolder with the VS2017 instance GUID (from now on referred to as `VS_GUID`). Note: `ProgramData` is a hidden folder.
2. (Optional) Create a backup of file `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances\{VS_GUID}\state.json` in another directory of your choice.
3. Edit file `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances\{VS_GUID}\state.json` (note: `VS_GUID` is the sub-folder name found in step 1) 
   and change `layoutPath` to your local layout folder and `installChannelUri` to the full path to `ChannelManifest.json` (which should be present in the layout folder root).

Example (when layout path is `D:\vs2017layout`):

```
(...)
"layoutPath":"D:\\vs2017layout",
"installChannelUri":"D:\\vs2017layout\\ChannelManifest.json"
(...)
```

4. Save `state.json` and launch `vs_professional_xxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyy.exe` (or equivalent) which is located in the layout folder. If it detects the updated installation files then the "download" progress should move to 100%.

This worked for me.